# How to extract specific value of a returned json object?

Tags: json, api, curl

I'm a bit lost. I have an API I connect to. It sends back a token. Then I use this token to get the balance.
If I console.log(data), I get everything in return. How do I get just the last part?
I just need: balance: 121.93

```
{"response":"Access Granted","response_code":"200","token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9leGFtcGxlLm9yZyIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL2V4YW1wbGUuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNTk0NjkwNzgzLCJuYmYiOjEzNTcwMDAwMDAsImV4cCI6MTU5NDY5MTM4MywiY29kZSI6ImNhbWlvbiJ9.xAJ30hi4DV_8o5PNIcZb0syS5nNnGUthz2ARPvPj8ls"}eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9leGFtcGxlLm9yZyIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL2V4YW1wbGUuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNTk0NjkwNzgzLCJuYmYiOjEzNTcwMDAwMDAsImV4cCI6MTU5NDY5MTM4MywiY29kZSI6ImNhbWlvbiJ9.xAJ30hi4DV_8o5PNIcZb0syS5nNnGUthz2ARPvPj8lsstdClass Object
(
    [balance] => 121.93
)
```

This is the code to call de data

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.post("cc-get-balance.php",
    {
      card:$('input[name=facture]').val()
    },
    function(data,status){
console.log(data);
 // $('#cc-balance').html(data);

 var myObj, x;
 myObj = data;
 x = myObj["balance"];
 document.getElementById("cc-balance").innerHTML = x;


    });
  });
});

});
```

Comment: Can you share the part of the code where you are printing the data

Comment: Thanks for replying. I added the code in my question above

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it turns out that javascript is not even used. The same call is made in php in a previous step.